# isspace macro conflicting with isspace function in locale_facets.h

Tags: c++, c, linux, cuda, cmake

I am building a cmake project that includes cuda code.  I am unable to compile one of the cuda files that includes several h files.  This is the compiler error I receive

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_ios.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ios:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:40,
                 from /home/pfeifs/Developement/Deform/LinuxDeform/LibDeform/Deform/cutil_comfunc.h:20,
                 from /home/pfeifs/Developement/Deform/LinuxDeform/LibDeform/Deform/VectorMathDef.h:22,
                 from /home/pfeifs/Developement/Deform/LinuxDeform/LibDeform/src/Deform/VectorMath.cu:15:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/locale_facets.h:2521:44: error: macro "isspace" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
```

`isspace()` is defined as a macro requiring one argument in `<ctype.h>` and declared as a templated function in `locale_facets.h`.  (These are both standard files.)  However at the beginning of  `locale_facets.h`, `<cctype>` is included and that undeclares the macro.

Any help or insight into this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to reorder the #include file order in your `cutil_comfunc.h` file so that the C++ includes precede the C includes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not mix and match C and C++ headers.

Use `#include <locale>` to pull in the `std::isspace` template with two parameters. Use `#include <cctype>` for a C++ safe include of `ctype.h` that won't cause conflicts with STL.

If you are writing a C program and don't want or need C++ then there should be no problem including `ctype.h` and using the `isspace` function with only one parameter.

Comment: +1 for first sentence if nothing else. I'm assuming the rest is right, but even if it weren't, the first sentence is the heart of the issue.

Comment: There was actually an additional ctype.h file in the include path of another random library I needed to include which apparently was earlier in the include path than the standard ctype library I meant to include.  I was able to get around that and everything worked correctly.

Comment: Perfect! Also there is no right way but I find I have less problems if my include order is like so: C++, 3rd party libs, my libs, local headers

Comment: Thanks for your help, macros are a pain.

Comment: This solution helped me solve the problem described here: http://bugs.python.org/issue10910